# Style specific gridline in highcharts polar/radar chart in R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter, radar-chart

I have a highcharts polar chart created with the highcharter package in R. I would like to style only one specific gridline, e.g. the gridline at value 100 in the example below. The code in the example styles all gridlines. How can I specify only one gridline to target? I would really appreciate your advice.

```
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(y=c(123,89,106))

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "line", polar = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = c("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"),
           labels = list(style = list(whiteSpace = 'nowrap'))) %>%
  hc_yAxis(max = plyr::round_any(max(df$y), 10, ceiling),
           gridLineColor = 'orange', gridLineWidth = 3) %>%
  hc_series(
    list(name = "Example chart",
         data = df$y,
         pointPlacement = "on",
         type = "line",
         color = "blue",
         showInLegend = F))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way be could be done by adding a plot line at a specific value on the yAxis.

```
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(y=c(123,89,106))

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "line", polar = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = c("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"),
           labels = list(style = list(whiteSpace = 'nowrap'))) %>%
  hc_yAxis(max = plyr::round_any(max(df$y), 10, ceiling),
           plotLines = list(list(value = 100,
                                 color = 'orange',
                                 width = 3)),
           gridLineColor = 'green') %>%
  hc_series(
    list(name = "Example chart",
         data = df$y,
         pointPlacement = "on",
         type = "line",
         color = "blue",
         showInLegend = F))
```

Answer (score 0):

In highcharts javascript we'd use the API (i.e., [Chart](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart), [Axis](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis), [Tick](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Tick) & others) to get hold of individual grid lines and set their properties:

```js
const firstTickNon80 = Math.min(...Object.keys(chart.yAxis[0].ticks).map(parseFloat).filter(x => x > 80)); 
// the index of the first grid line > 80 is firstTickNon80 converted to string

chart.yAxis[0].ticks[''+firstTickNon80].gridLine
    .attr('stroke','orange')
    .attr('stroke-width','3px');
```

That can be injected to R in highcharter at the chart `render` event:

```R
library(highcharter)

df <- data.frame(y=c(123,89,106))

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "line", polar = TRUE, events = list(
    render = JS("
    function(){
        // here, this is the Chart instance
        const firstTickNon80 = Math.min(...Object.keys(this.yAxis[0].ticks).map(parseFloat).filter(x => x > 80));
        this.yAxis[0].ticks[''+firstTickNon80].gridLine.attr('stroke','orange').attr('stroke-width','3px');
    }"))) %>%

  hc_xAxis(categories = c("Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3"),
           labels = list(style = list(whiteSpace = 'nowrap'))) %>%
  hc_yAxis(max = plyr::round_any(max(df$y), 10, ceiling)) %>%
  hc_series(
    list(name = "Example chart",
         data = df$y,
         pointPlacement = "on",
         type = "line",
         color = "blue",
         showInLegend = F))
```